# How to stop time activated functions

Tags: javascript, timer

You can see that I have a stop button, but the code is not correct since the script will not stop when I press that button, so how can I do it? And is I possible that when I press stop it stops when I press stop, and it starts where it stopped again when I press the start button again?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="timedText()">Start</button>

  <button onclick="clearTimeout(timeout)">Stop</button>


  <div id="leser">
    <iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=good_deals&sort=n&app=433850_1"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="leser2">
    <iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=good_deals&sort=n&app=433850_1"></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>
    var timeout;
    function timedText() {
       timeout = setTimeout(myTimeout1, 5000) 
       timeout = setTimeout(myTimeout2, 10000) 
       timeout = setTimeout(myTimeout3, 15000) 
}

 function stopTimeout() {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
 }
 function myTimeout1() {
   document.getElementById("leser").innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin%3A+Flaming+Skull+Face+Bandana%22"></iframe>';;
}
 function myTimeout2() {
   document.getElementById("leser").innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=Skin%3A+Pinstripe+Suit+Jacket"></iframe>';
}
 function myTimeout3() {
   document.getElementById("leser").innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin%3A+Pinstripe+Slacks%22"></iframe>';
}
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) returns a reference to the timer, you can store that in a variable then use [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) to stop it

Comment: Similar to [clearInterval not working | undefined](//stackoverflow.com/a/41498653)

Comment: @ArunPJohny could you maybe help me out a little and show me an example? Im afraid i dont really understand sorry, im very new to this..

Comment: @MathiasHermansen something like https://jsfiddle.net/f7xgeqLm/1/ - may not be the correct one as we don't have the complete details of what you are trying to do

Comment: @ArunPJohny take a look on this https://jsfiddle.net/99tgy8mv/ - When i start it it counts from 1-8 and repeats, but i want to add a button to stop it if press it, and if possible i would like to be able to push the start button again and it will continue from where it stopped.

Comment: and with the one you made the start button did not work, when i pressed it nothing happened.. sorry @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `clearInterval` requires a scheduled `setInterval` result to clear. You are using `setTimeout`. The difference is that an interval set with `setInterval` will call *repeatedly*, over and over again, at the specific delay, until it is stopped. `setTimeout`, however, will only be called *once*.

In order to cancel your timeout or interval, first you need to be able to reference it. This is done by setting a variable to the return value of your timeout, such as in:

```
var someTimeout = setTimeout(someFunction, 10000);
```

In order to clear this timeout, you can then go:

```
clearTimeout(someTimeout);
```

Thus, you must get the return value from your `setTimeout` in order to stop it later - which you do by passing the return value to `clearTimeout`.

Here is a fully working example of the JS code needed to start and stop a timeout:

```
var timeout;
function startTimeout() {
  // Set a timeout for 10 seconds from now and store it in `timeout`.
  timeout = setTimeout(callbackFunc, 10000);
}

function stopTimeout() {
  // Clear the timeout stored in `timeout`.
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

// This function is called when the timeout happens.
function callbackFunc() {
  alert("Timeout has been triggered!");
}
```

Here is your code, adapted to work correctly (although I recommend figuring it out yourself using the information I've given above instead, it's more than enough and you'll actually learn that way.):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="timedText()">Start</button>

  <button onclick="clearInterval(setTimeout)">Stop time</button>


  <div id="leser">
    <iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=good_deals&sort=n&app=433850_1"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="leser2">
    <iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=good_deals&sort=n&app=433850_1"></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>
    var timeoutOne, timeoutTwo, timeoutThree;
    function timedText() {
       timeoutOne = setTimeout(myTimeout1, 5000) 
       timeoutTwo = setTimeout(myTimeout2, 10000) 
       timeoutThree = setTimeout(myTimeout3, 15000) 
}

 function stopTimeout() {
   clearTimeout(timeoutOne);
   clearTimeout(timeoutTwo);
   clearTimeout(timeoutThree);
 }
 function myTimeout1() {
   document.getElementById("leser").innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin%3A+Flaming+Skull+Face+Bandana%22"></iframe>';;
}
 function myTimeout2() {
   document.getElementById("leser").innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=Skin%3A+Pinstripe+Suit+Jacket"></iframe>';
}
 function myTimeout3() {
   document.getElementById("leser").innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin%3A+Pinstripe+Slacks%22"></iframe>';
}
  </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so how should the stop button code look like for the code you made here?

Comment: @MathiasHermansen Create a variable for each of your three `setTimeout` calls, (for example: `var theTimeoutVariable = setTimeout(foo, 10000);`) and then, when you want to clear them, use `clearTimeout(theTimeoutVariable)`

Comment: i updated my code now, did i do things correct like that? And thank you very much for helping me out here!

Comment: @MathiasHermansen You're very close! You'll have to have a separate variable for each timeout, and call `clearTimeout` once for each variable, otherwise it only clears the last timeout! I've added a snippet to my answer with the correct way of going about it, in case you need it.

Comment: By the way, @MathiasHermansen, people on SO don't like it when you edit the code in your question to be correct / different! It's a better idea to add your updated code in an edit below the original code, marked with a label like "**Edit:**". It's much better because it doesn't make it look like people are "correcting" problems that don't exist in your changed code after it's been changed.

Comment: Okey thank you very much! Im gonna read trough it all some time now, i want to learn it! But i tried the code and the stop button did now work :/

Comment: Okey thank you for saying that, i will keep that in mind for next time, im very sorry since im new here and im very new with programming, this is one of the projects im doing to learn more. But i like this site and the help i get here, learning alittle all the time!

Comment: @MathiasHermansen I've just figured out *another* reason why the stop button won't work — It's not calling `stopTimeout()`! You should update that and try again.

Comment: okey i changed the 'clearInterval(setTimeout)' with 'stopTimeout(setTimeout)' and now it works!  That was correct right?

Comment: And if i want it to repeat if i dont press the stop button, how can i do that? I should use the setInterval instead of setTimeout?

Comment: @MathiasHermansen You don't need to run `stopTimeout(setTimeout)`, just calling `stopTimeout()` will do fine! It's your own function!

Comment: @MathiasHermansen If you want it to run repeatedly, you can replace all instances of `Timeout` with `Interval` in your code (`setTimeout` becomes `setInterval`, `clearTimeout` becomes `clearInterval`) - That will use the interval system instead of timeouts, which repeats until cleared.

Comment: Okey thank you alot for taking time to help me out with this, I got to do what i wanted now and i also learned some new things!

Comment: @MathiasHermansen I'm glad I could help! Would you mind marking this answer as the accepted answer, if I was able to solve your problem?